# How do I implement PayPal Express Checkout in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

how i create express checkout paypal in asp.net ?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this CodeProject article about integrating various PayPal features into ASP.NET (there's a whole section for Express Checkout):

[Introduction to PayPal for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers)

Comment: @GeorgeWBush - I updated the link. I may come back and add more detail as well but given this is such an old answer, the content may also be out of date.