# How to integrate Paypal Api for express checkout in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, paypal-sandbox

I have found [this code](http://blogs.effectlabs.com/post/2011/11/07/Paypal-Express-Checkout-with-C-using-Paypal-web-services.aspx) online.

But the function `paypalAAInt` does not exist in the PayPal API according to the [WSDL](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl). Can anyone help me to how to integrate PayPal express checkout in Asp.Net

```
CustomSecurityHeaderType type = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();

type.Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType()
{
    Username = "thakur_1322207622_biz_api1.gmail.com",
    Password = "1322207646",
    Signature = "An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-Asr3E2CXn-a5b6uZmCDTPNNvpGBl"
};

SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType sdt = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
sdt.NoShipping = "1";

PaymentDetailsType pdt = new PaymentDetailsType()
{
    OrderDescription = "Order for 1 year" + Request.Cookies["username"].Value,
    OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType()
    {
        currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD,
        Value = "95.40"
    }
};
sdt.PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType[] { pdt };
sdt.CancelURL = "http://localhost:2326/MusicStore/Default.aspx";
sdt.ReturnURL = "http://localhost:2326/MusicStore/regsuccessfull.aspx";

SetExpressCheckoutReq req = new SetExpressCheckoutReq()
{
    SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType()
    {
        SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = sdt,
        Version = "60.0"
    }
};

var resp = paypalAAInt.SetExpressCheckout(ref type, req);

if (resp.Errors != null && resp.Errors.Length > 0)
{
    // errors occured
    throw new Exception("Exception(s) occured when calling PayPal. First exception: " +
            resp.Errors[0].LongMessage);
}

Response.Redirect(string.Format("{0}?cmd=_express-checkout&token={1}", 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSubmitUrl"], resp.Token));
```

This is the code which I am using, but the function `paypalAAInt` does not exist in the PayPal API. Which function should be used instead of `paypalAAInt`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement PayPal Express Checkout in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086796/how-do-i-implement-paypal-express-checkout-in-asp-net)

Comment: please, make sure your answer is not already answered in the forum first, when you write your question, the existing questions come up automatically, and the one I mention does! If you also Google for `Paypal Express C#` the old question comes up...

Comment: Yes, i have seen the question by paresh, but my question is how do i get response from paypal api web service to recieve the token???

Comment: I keep reading your question... it mentions nothing like you say in your comment! Your question specifically and simply says: **Can anyone help me to how to integrate paypal express checkout in asp.net** and for that, it's a duplicated question.

Comment: I have edited the question can you please help

Answer (score 1):

The Method `SetExpressCheckout` is available if you have an object of `PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient` and that should become available if you have added a web reference to the WSDL.

Here is your missing line:

```
PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient paypalAAInt = new PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient();
```